# How to convert matlab numeric to POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

*I've udpdated this question because I've been told that the column of numbers use the Matlab origin = 1 January 2000 and the units are in seconds*  I'm still getting stuck though.

I have a column of date/time values expressed as numbers - these have come from Matlab. I would like to convert these to POSIXct in R.

Here is an example of what I've tried with a single value.

```
as.POSIXct(736908.0041, origin = "2000-01-01", tz="UTC")
```

But this returns "2000-01-09 12:41:48 UTC", which is not correct.
The correct date should be 2017-08-02, I'm not sure about the time.

I have tried multiplying the number by both 60 and 3600 in case the units weren't really in seconds, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: What is `736908.0041` here?

Comment: I have a column of numbers that I'd like to convert to date/time. `736908.0041` is the first value in the column

Comment: I mean does it represent time in seconds on another unit?

Comment: I have that very question myself. I'm not sure how to approach this given that I lack those details. The one thing I do know is the approximate equivalent date/time.

Comment: I've just learned that the origin is 1 January 2000 and the units are in seconds. This column of numbers was produced in Matlab. Have edited the question to reflect this

Comment: Try out `as.POSIXct((736908.0041 - 719529)*86400, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")`